# How to combine two queries in a foreach loop in PHP?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

Facebook API can give the pages a user admins. Suppose that it returns me the following array. Unfortunately it does not return the name of it or a url.

**This turns me a list of page IDs.**

```
$results = $facebook->api('/fql', array('q'=>'SELECT page_id, type FROM page_admin WHERE uid = me()'));

foreach($results['data'] as $result) {
    echo $result['page_id'], '<br />';
}
```

**Using the follow I echo the name of the page ID.**

```
$pagename = $facebook->api('/fql', array('q'=>'SELECT name FROM page WHERE page_id = 230127303706132'));
echo $pagename['data'][0]['name'];
```

My question is how can I have a list of the page names in an efficient way?
**My guess is that I have to put the query inside the foreach loop.**

Comment: do you need the page names without using foreach ?

Comment: @SujathanNedumparambu If that possible then yes. Any way that will show me all the names.

Comment: using graph api it is very easy to fetch the page names.The only thing is you must have an access token.

Comment: @SujathanNedumparambu Does the access token is created when someone is just logged in his account OR after he is authorized to use the facebook app?

Comment: access token is created when someone gave permission that are asked by the app and authorized to use the facebook app.For more details [view authentication in facebook application](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First grab the `page_ids`

```
$results = $facebook->api('/fql', array('q'=>'SELECT page_id, type FROM page_admin WHERE uid = me()'));

$page_ids = array();
foreach($results['data'] as $result) {
    $page_ids[] = $result['page_id'];
}
```

Then get page names

```
$pagenames = $facebook->api('/fql', array('q'=>'SELECT name FROM page WHERE page_id IN (' . join(',', $page_ids) .')' ));

// list all page names
foreach($pagenames['data'] as $result) {
    echo $result['name'], '<br />';
}
```

Get it in one query

```
$pagenames = $facebook->api('/fql', array('q' => 'SELECT name FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM page_admin  WHERE  uid=me())'));

// list all page names
foreach($pagenames['data'] as $result) {
    echo $result['name'], '<br />';
}
```

Comment: This works great. One question though. Is there a possibility of joining the two queries and use one foreach loop?

Comment: I am trying to make it work but I can't (the all in one query). I typed the `$pagenames=` at the beginning.

Comment: @Kaoukkos It works fine for me. you might have to authenticated via facebook first though (logged in with facebook)

Comment: Please give me a contact detail if you are interested in a freelance work.

Answer (score 1):

```
try this

$fql=https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT name FROM page WHERE page_id in(SELECT page_id, type FROM page_admin WHERE uid = me())&access_token=xxxxxxxx;
$page_names =json_decode(file_get_contents($fql));
print_r($page_names);
It will show an array of page names.
```